# I already have Nextjs app with tailwind and daisyUI. I Trying to implement Cypress

Tags: next.js, cypress, tailwind-css

I already have the Nextjs app with tailwind and daisyUI. I Trying to implement Cypress but can not configure it and it only appears de html.

// package.json

```js
 "scripts": {
    
    "tailwind-generate": " npx tailwindcss --input styles/globals.css --output styles/tailwind-generated.css"
    }
```

// cypress/**tests**/Button.cy.js

```js
import { mount } from 'cypress/react'
import Button from '../../components/Inputs/Button'

describe('<Button >', () => {
  it('mount', () => {
    mount(<Button label={'Hola'} />, { stylesheet: '@/styles/tailwind-generated.css' })
  })
})
```

but nothing happens

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a simple pre-generated style sheet, you should be able to use it by just importing it.

```js
import { mount } from 'cypress/react'
import Button from '../../components/Inputs/Button'
import from '../../styles/tailwind-generated.css'  // path may need adjusting

describe('<Button >', () => {
  it('mount', () => {
    mount(<Button label={'Hola'} />)
  })
})
```

For CDN based styles

```js
describe('<Button >', () => {
  it('mount', () => {
    mount(<Button label={'Hola'} />, {
      stylesheets: [
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css',
      ],)
  })
})
```

Comment: I already try these... nothing. It should works. The first option it drops the name " `Button` is defined multiple times "

Comment: Sorry my bad - the CSS should be imported anonymously (without Button).

Comment: The problem with this is I am using nextjs, so i canot import global css in other place than _app, and if I importe as .module.css, then con use *, html or body tags ...

Comment: The thing is, when you use `mount(Component)` you are not using NextJs. The Component is just a React building block, and the component-test just runs like a React test. To test NextJs you need to use e2e testing not component testing.